# Using a aliased column in the JOIN predicate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

**customers table:**

| name | email |
| --- | --- |
| saqib | saqib@gmail.com |
| scott | scott@google.com |
| amy | amy@wd.com |

**account_description table:**

| account_type | description |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | personal |
| 14 | corporate |

Is there way to re-write the following query without CTE or subquery?

```
with cte_customers as (
  select 
    case
      when email ilike '%gmail.com' or email ilike '%hotmail.com' or email ilike '%yahoo.com' then 13
      else 14
    end as account_type_generated
    , name 
  from customers
)
select * 
from cte_customers
inner join account_description on account_type_generated = account_description.account_type  ;
```

SQL Fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c5KCj5sCcJXmYxsHDCNGAF/0

Comment: Which DB engine are you actually using? Please remove the irrelevant tags

Comment: Please also [edit] your question to show an example of the result you want. I suspect a `CASE` statement will still be involved in the answer

Comment: Why does it matter if you use a subquery? Personally I favour `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to avoid repeating code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the join and case WHen to the SELECT that you have in the CTE

---

**Query #1**

```
with cte_customers as (
  select 
    case
      when email ilike '%gmail.com' or email ilike '%hotmail.com' or email ilike '%yahoo.com' then 13
      else 14
    end as account_type_generated
    , name 
  from customers
)
select * 
from cte_customers
inner join account_description on account_type_generated = account_description.account_type  ;
```

| account_type_generated | name | account_type | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | saqib | 13 | personal |
| 14 | scott | 14 | corporate |
| 14 | amy | 14 | corporate |

---

**Query #2**

```
select 
    case
      when email ilike '%gmail.com' or email ilike '%hotmail.com' or email ilike '%yahoo.com' then 13
      else 14
    end as account_type_generated
    , name 
    ,account_description.*
  from customers
  inner join account_description on     (case
      when email ilike '%gmail.com' or email ilike '%hotmail.com' or email ilike '%yahoo.com' then 13
      else 14
    end) 
  = account_description.account_type;
```

| account_type_generated | name | account_type | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | saqib | 13 | personal |
| 14 | scott | 14 | corporate |
| 14 | amy | 14 | corporate |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c5KCj5sCcJXmYxsHDCNGAF/1)

Answer (score 1):

just put the CASE into the ON:

```
select 
    case
      when email ilike '%gmail.com' or email ilike '%hotmail.com' or email ilike '%yahoo.com' then 13
      else 14
    end as account_type_generated
    , name 
    ,ad.*
  from customers as c
  inner join account_description as ad
    on case
      when email ilike '%gmail.com' or email ilike '%hotmail.com' or email ilike '%yahoo.com' then 13
      else 14
    end = ad.account_type  ;
```

[image]

but then given the `account_type_generated` is duplicate, it could be drop:

```
select 
    c.name 
    ,ad.*
from customers as c
join account_description as ad
    on case
      when c.email ilike '%gmail.com' or c.email ilike '%hotmail.com' or c.email ilike '%yahoo.com' then 13
      else 14
    end = ad.account_type  ;
```

and the CASE could be rewritten as an IFF

```
select 
    c.name 
    ,ad.*
from customers as c
join account_description as ad
    on IFF( c.email ilike '%gmail.com' or c.email ilike '%hotmail.com' or c.email ilike '%yahoo.com', 13, 14) = ad.account_type  ;
```

This is all on Snowflake.